# Дать разрешения на использование камеры в веб части гибридного приложения

Tags: android, android-studio

добрый день!
Есть мобильное приложение, которое содержит в себе веб-часть (WebView), в веб-части есть кнопка "сделать фото", но она не срабатывает (с браузера все работает).
В манифесте разрешение на камеру есть. В чем может быть подвох (хитрость)? Спасибо

Comment: Как реализовано открытие камеры? Какая версия Android? На 6+ нужно дополнительно запрашивать разрешения в рантайме

Comment: пока что, прописано разрешение в манифесте, min API 19